# What is wrong in my attempt in permutations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What is the number of different ways in which $8$ persons can stand in a row so between two particular persons $A$ and $B$ there are always two other persons?

Now, consider A _ _ B | _ _ _ _

Consider A _ _ B as $1$ person, so there are $5!$ ways. Now the blanks can be filled in $6!$ ways and then I multiply by $2$ because $A$ and $B$ can interchange places. Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In your $5!$ permutations, you're already counting some of the $6!$ permutations of the blanks.

Comment: how so? i havenot filled in yet

Comment: If you haven't filled, then $5!$ is for what?

Comment: A..B can go in 5 places, and then the two people can swap - so I think A__B can be configured in 10 ways, not 2 x 5! ways - other than that, it looks sound to me - I think you have mis-thought 5!

Comment: Are there to be *exactly* $2$ people between $A$ and $B$ or *at least* $2$ people? I see you have interpreted *exactly* but are you sure that's what the question is asking?

Comment: BTW I'm assuming that A and B are specific people - that's right isn't it?

Comment: yes they are specific

Comment: @Cato yeah thanks your diagnose was correct

Comment: You are arranging people twice, once when you arrange the five objects consisting of the block of four seats with persons A and B on the ends and the other four people and again when you fill the six open seats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you made was arranging the same people twice, once when you arranged the block of four people with A and B on the ends and the other people and once when you filled the six open positions.

> In how many ways can eight people be arranged in a row so that there are exactly two people between persons A and B?

Since there are a total of eight people, the block of four people must start in one of the first five positions.  There are two ways to choose whether person A or B is at the left end of the block.  The remaining six positions can be filled in $6!$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$5 \cdot 2 \cdot 6!$$
seating arrangements in which there are exactly two people between persons A and B.

> In how many ways can eight people be arranged in a row so that there are at least two people between persons A and B?

This is another possible interpretation which N. Shales raised in the comments.

We can count such arrangements by subtracting the number of arrangements in which fewer than two people are between A and B.  Reasoning as above, there are 
$$7 \cdot 2 \cdot 6!$$
arrangements in which A and B are adjacent since there are seven potential starting positions, two ways to decide whether A or B stands at the left end of the block, and $6!$ ways to arrange the remaining six people in the remaining six positions.  By similar reasoning, there are

> $$6 \cdot 2 \cdot 6!$$

arrangements in which exactly one person stands between A and B.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which at least two people stand between A and B is

> $$8! - 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 6! - 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 6!$$

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There are $\fbox{$\fbox{A - - B}\space \fbox{- - - -}$} = 5! = 120$ ways.</strike>

Now, $\fbox{A x y B}$ is same as $\fbox{B y x A}$ and $\fbox{A y x B}$ is same as $\fbox{B x y A}$, so there is only $2$ other possible ways.

So, total number of ways $ = 5! \times 2! = 120\times 2 = 240$ ways.

#### Comment:

As you have already counted other four empty places in $5!$, so you have to arrange other two places between $A$ and $B$ that is only $2$ ways. Now we have done.

---

#### Update:

Total number of ways:

1. $\fbox{ A - - B - - - -}$
2. $\fbox{ - A - - B - - -}$
3. $\fbox{ - - A - - B - -}$
4. $\fbox{ - - - A - - B -}$
5. $\fbox{ - - - - A - - B}$
6. $\fbox{ B - - A - - - -}$
7. $\fbox{ - B - - A - - -}$
8. $\fbox{ - - B - - A - -}$
9. $\fbox{ - - - B - - A -}$
10. $\fbox{ - - - - B - - A}$

And every combination has $6$ empty cells that can arranged in $6!$ ways, so total number of ways $= 10\times 6! = 10\times 720 = 7200$ ways.

Comment: Be careful:  While it is true that there are $5!$ ways of arranging a block of four positions and four other positions, you have to select which people stand between A and B and the order in which they stand.  Once you have done that, you can arrange the five objects.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thanks for pointing out.